# Find the derivative of an integral, inside the integral we find a partial derivative

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function of $t$ given by an integral of the sort:
$$E(t) = \int_a^bf_t(x,t)^2dx$$
And I want to know if there is a way I can find the derivative of $E$ with respect to $t$.
For example, my first guess was
$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{1}{3}f_t(x,t)^3$$
But this just seems too nice to be true. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The writing $f_t(x,t)$ is quite ambigus....

Comment: I assume $f_t(x,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst That's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

It will be $\frac{dE}{dt} = \int_a^b 2f_{tt}(x,t)f_t(x,t)dx$ by the chain rule. We have taken the derivative wrt to $t$ inside the integral. Note that the limits do not depend on $t$ so we don't use FTC here.